# Concatenate multiple files to multiple files without for loop

Tags: bash, cat

Suppose we have some files,

```
touch {1..10}-{1..10}.dat
```

which are to be concatenated with respect to the second digit. The for loop solution would be

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    cat *-${i}.dat > ${i}.out
done
```

Is it possible to match the contents of one glob in the redirect? Something like

```
cat *-*.dat > *.out
```

is obviously ambiguous, but I thought something like

```
cat *-{1..10}.dat > {1..10}.out
```

should work. Is there a straightforward non-for loop solution here?

Comment: That loop is the straightforward solution. Brace expansion can't really expand the same value to multiple places on the command line by itself, and it doesn't really make it easy to create multiple commands either. You could build up some non-straightforward solution, but that would just be silly and would make the script much harder to understand for any future readers.

Comment: Okay, figured as much. Nested for loops get annoying when typing directly into the command line and not everything should need its own script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something crazy like

```
$ eval "bash -c 'n=\$1; echo \$n' cmd "{1..2}\;

1
2
```

Understanding is easier with `echo`:

```
$ echo "bash -c 'n=\$1; echo \$n' cmd "{1..2}\;

bash -c 'n=$1; echo $n' cmd 1; bash -c 'n=$1; echo $n' cmd 2;
```

For your case:

```
eval "bash -c 'n=\$1; cat *-\$n.dat > \$n.out' cmd "{1..10}\;
```

Comment: Or just `eval 'n='{1..10}'; cat *-$n > $n.out;'`, if you don't mind the brace expansion being in the middle. Could also do it with a function. Anyway, whatever the form, that's exactly the type of crazy non-straightforward solution I would hope people will never use in production...